# Как распарсить код

Tags: c++, windows-8

Добрый день! Имеется текст, который содержит код на с++. Код состоит из описании нескольких классов(может быть наследование и полиморфизм) и основной программы, которая создает объекты этих классов. Методы классов не реализуются, только описываются(прототип). Хотелось бы по рассуждать как распарсить данный текст и как сохранить полученную информацию для дальнейшего использования.

Пример текста:

```
class ClassA (Может быть class ClassA:ClassB)
{
public:
  ClassA(); (Может быть не сколько параметров)

  int Print(int); (Функций может и не быть)
private:
 int y;
};

int main()
{
  int y = 0;
 ClassA foo;
y = foo.Print(10);   

 return 0;
}
```

В итоге нужно получить объектную модель с++. В итоге должна быть таблица того, как размещается это программа в оперативной памяти.
Никакие ссылки, указатели, выражения кроме = не нужно обрабатывать

Мне интересно с чего начать. Пока что мысль такая: Считываю по символьно до первого разделительного знака(space, ;, {, }, (, ), =).
Как дошли до этого знака идет сравнение: если class, то создаем структуру с 2 полями: название класса и структура для содержимого класса(возможно еще поля понадобятся для адреса размера и т.д.).
Структура для содержимого класса будет содержать следующие поля: 
- Тип данных(конструктор это или деструктор, переменная, функция)
- Имя содержимого
- Модификатор (private public и тд)
- Возвращаемый тип(Для функций, в других случаях пустое поле)
- структуры для аргументов функций по аналогии(связынный список)

И вот потом по этим структурам я думаю возможно вывести в таблицу расположение данных в памяти ооп

Самое главное не нужна проверка на ошибки, текст должен содержать код без ошибок

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример исходных данных (текст, который хотите парсить) и пример результата (что вы хотите получить). Пока что не очень ясно, почему вам, например, компилятор c++ не подходит.

Comment: Распарсить текст на C++ _очень сложно_. Если есть какой-нибудь обходной путь, лучше применить его. Например, включить этот код в процесс компиляции. (Кстати, если вы на линукс-системе, то компилятор является частью системы, и вы можете просто воспользоваться им в рантайме.)

Comment: Все зависит от того, какая именно информация о коде вас интересует. Я не думаю, что вас интересует все одновременно (например, я не думаю, что вам нужно знать, сколько бинарных операторов содержит код )

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил.

Comment: @helldrg плюс вам. :)

Comment: Если вам нужна информация, как данные будут располагаться в памяти, то воспользуйтесь линковщиком. В нём есть ключ (не помню какой), который позволяет сгенерировать map-файл. В нём будет информация обо всех объектных модулях, переменных, классах, их расположение в памяти и другая полезная информация. Но лично я считаю её полезной, только если писать под голое железо: микроконтроллеры, загрузчики,  модули ядра.

Comment: Выше еще добавил информации по своим соображениям) Мне интересно правильно ли я делаю, что бы потом в тупик не зайти.

Comment: Самое главное не нужна проверка на ошибки, текст должен содержать код без ошибок

Comment: Если вас интересует как биты struct в памяти упакованы, то попробуйте [pahole и/или `clang -Wpadded`](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_tools). Чтобы извлечь общую информацию из C++ кода, посмотрите [как cppyy (позволяет c++ код для pypy оборачивать)  использует cling, написанный поверх LLVM/clang](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cppyy.html)

Comment: Не, мне интересно, как я описал выше можно подойти к задаче или по другому надо